# assigning results of sql query to local variables

Tags: sql

Result of a SQL query can be assigned to a local variable like this:

```
declare @name varchar(30)
select @name = (select name from dummyTable where id = 10)
```

But what if I have to assign multiple column values to multiple local variables?

Say I have @address, @serialNumber, @grade, @phoneNumber.

Do I have to perform multiple select statements? Like this

```
select @address = (select address from dummyTable where id = 10)
select @serialNumber = (select serialNumber from dummyTable where id = 10)
....
```

Is there a way I can do this assignment in 1 select statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this below

```
select @address = address , 
       @serialNumber = serialNumber 
from dummyTable where id = 10
```